# Kafka Connect sending struct object rather than JSON

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka sink connector to deserialize Avro data which is being sent by a kafka streaming application. I am using confluent's Avroconverter in the worker configuration, but I am getting a struct object as output from connect application instead of JSON object. How can I get a JSON object?
Below is the configuration I am using in connect-avro-standalone.properties file,

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

Comment: Can you share the content of your worker configuration file?

Comment: If any one have any pointers please help on this issue.

Comment: Can you share a sample message/data?

Comment: Also, what client are you using? A Java one?